# Entity Framework "Code supposed to be unreachable" on agrigated include expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern

**First**

I have created this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/sturlath/sturla.io.GenericExpressionMapping) **that only needs to be F5 to hit this error** so it should be easy for you to try this out. All links in this question lead to that repo.

**Flow of code**

The [following expression code](https://github.com/sturlath/sturla.io.GenericExpressionMapping/blob/aab065232ab4583102e8d641fcbde56f23af2549/sturla.io.GenericExpressionMapping/Controllers/CompanyController.cs#L33) in my controller is where I want to give the front end developers the power to include the relations they need.

```
// The included tables I want to control from my controller
Expression<Func<CompanyDto, object>>[] includes = { x => x.Employees, x => x.Cars };

var companyDto2 = await service.GetByIdAsync(1, includes).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

and then in my service layer [I map the dto includes to my entity includes](https://github.com/sturlath/sturla.io.GenericExpressionMapping/blob/a6b000849bd2087143bf5b3c64383fcbe7fad0b1/ServiceLayer/GenericService.cs#L27) and send them to the repository

```
var entityIncludes = mapper.Map<Expression<Func<Entity, object>>[]>(includes);

var result = await repository.GetByIdAsync(id, entityIncludes).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

**The error**

When I run the include expressions in my [repository](https://github.com/sturlath/sturla.io.GenericExpressionMapping/blob/a6b000849bd2087143bf5b3c64383fcbe7fad0b1/DataLayer/GenericRepository.cs#L20) I get the following error.

> "Code supposed to be unreachable"

Here are **two examples** of things I have tried that throw this error.

**First attempt**

This was attempt from [enter link description here](https://deviq.com/specification-pattern/)

```
var queryableResultWithIncludes = includes
.Aggregate(dbContext.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable(),
(current, include) => current.Include(include));

// return the result of the query using the specification's criteria expression
var result = queryableResultWithIncludes.AsEnumerable();

// Here we get "Code supposed to be unreachable"
var neverHappens = result .ToList();
```

**Second attempt**

```
// Second attempts
if (includes.Length > 0)
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> set = includes
       .Aggregate<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>, IQueryable<TEntity>>
       (dbContext.Set<TEntity>(), (current, expression) => current.Include(expression));

    // Here we also get "Code supposed to be unreachable"
    return await set.SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == id).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

**Summary**

What am I missing? Am I doing some kind of anti pattern stuff? I need some EF expert to tell me please :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I was suspecting, the issue has nothing in common with EF, but invalid expression produced by AutoMapper expression translation here:

```
var entityIncludes = mapper.Map<Expression<Func<Entity, object>>[]>(includes);
```

It can be seen by expanding the `entityIncludes` variable in Locals/Watch window - you will see the exception in question for debug view or `Parameters` property of `LambdaExpression`.

With that said, the issue is caused by improper AutoMapper configuration, specifically the lack of `AddExpressionMapping()`. You did that for AutoMapper global configuration, but your code is using dependency injection, so you need to do it there, e.g.

*Current*

```
services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
// Auto Mapper Configurations
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.DisableConstructorMapping();
    cfg.AddExpressionMapping();
    cfg.AddProfile<CompanyProfile>();
});
```

*Should be*

```
services.AddAutoMapper(cfg =>
{
    cfg.DisableConstructorMapping();
    cfg.AddExpressionMapping();    
}, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```